# How to assign a default role to a user in Many-To-Many relation table without adding that role as new to the Role table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller, ef-code-first

I am still learning to code and this is my first question. Any help to phrase it better or to add something that is missing is appreciated.

I have a table User (Name, Surname...) and a table Role (Name, Description...). A many-to-many relation table UserRole connects their IDs.

```
registeredUser.Roles.Add(DefaultDataProvider.Roles[RoleName.Guest]);
await dataRepository.CreateAsync(registeredUser);  
await bridgeRepository.CreateAsync(registeredUser);
```

When a user is registered s/he is assigned a default role of "Guest". However, on registration the program is trying to add a *new* role "Guest" to the table and throws an exception because it already exists.

I wanted to make it check if it exists before trying to add it to the Role table by making manually that relation table but then I have 2 tables UserRole, one that I coded and one that was generated through migration. So I tried to stop it from generating the second table by adding `[NotMapped]`
annotation and by using Fluent API's Ignore Method (not at the same time). Neither worked and threw an exception:
`"ExceptionMessage": "A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'User' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Role'."`

I know about the Attach method but I can't use it because I need to use a third party dll for managing data and I only have access to db structure.

**My primary goal is to assign the default role to a new user without the program trying to add the role as if it was new.**

---

I am using EF 6.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

I would first find the Role entity with a new method:

```
var role = roleRepository.GetRoleByName(RoleName.Guest)
```

then add that to the navigation prop in Person entity:

```
registeredUser.Roles.Add(role);
```

Completely pseudo code, but I hope you understand? The point is to first find a reference to the Role object and the map it to Person.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I am trying out your solution, but I encountered yet another related problem. Once I resolve it, I think this will work.